# Do I need the exact velocity when experimenting with sliding coins?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, momentum, home-experiment

I'm doing a home experiment but it's not going very well.

I'm pushing coins on a table.

I'm taking the time for how long it takes coin A to hit coin B and then I divide it by the time between them to find the velocity of coin A.

I say that the velocity times the mass of coin A should equal the velocity of coin B times its mass plus the velocity of coin A times it's mass (after).

My calculation isn't making any sense. Is this experiment not possible with friction on the table? Do I need the exact velocity when it hits?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you do need the exact velocity when it hits, and the exact velocities when they shoot off. Theres a fair bit of friction involved, therefore it can be tricky to calculate the velocity. Also momentum is conserved along a direction. Did you take that into account?

Comment: Yes. Looks like I have to botch this experiment :(